# Clicking on referenced dlls don't show path in properties window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, properties

When I click on the referenced dll in my project "A" and I have my properties window open then I was expecting to see the full path of the dll and other details. For some reason I can't see those dll details in properties :(

I tried to clean/rebuild but still doesn't work. Although for my other project "B" it does work. That means there is definitely something wrong with the Any ideas?

Here is the screenshot of project "A". So I have clicked the Microsoft.CSharp dll but properties still show some other dll/project details.

Thanks

[image]

![enter image description here][2]
![enter image description here][3]

Comment: I used those DLLs for example to display that I can't see there referenced paths. Really important are those DLLs which are NOT part of .Net.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what I did - may be recompiled and closed VS and installed resharper. Now all paths are showing up.

Comment: The screenshot shows you looking at the Solution properties, not the properties of the reference.  So you either just clicked the wrong node or some kind of addin is messing with it.  Possible, "Enterprise Library 5 Assembly Set" isn't standard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what but may be cleaning, recompiling and reopening the solution fixed the issue.
[image]

[image]